# Drawing custom plots and spacing them in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am actually struggling to draw a custom plot which I had made using MS powerpoint. I got a lot of help from my previous question but still I am not able to resolve the placement issues and various other mistakes, in order to make the copy of the figure which I have.

**The image which I wish to come up with:**

[image]

**I tried coding this up:**

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifnumcomp
\usepackage{listofitems} % for \readlist to create arrays

\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\colorlet{mywhite}{white!80!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{mydarkred}{myred!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{myblue!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkgreen}{mygreen!40!black}
\tikzstyle{node}=[very thick,circle,draw=myblue,minimum size=22,inner sep=0.5,outer sep=0.6]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[->,thick,mydarkblue,shorten >=1]
\tikzset{ % node styles, numbered for easy mapping with \nstyle
  node 1/.style={node,mydarkgreen,draw=mywhite,fill=mywhite!25},
  node 2/.style={node,mydarkblue,draw=mywhite,fill=mywhite!20},
  node 3/.style={node,mydarkred,draw=mywhite,fill=mywhite!20},
}
\def\nstyle{int(\lay<\Nnodlen?min(2,\lay):3)} % map layer number onto 1, 2, or 3

\begin{document}


% NEURAL NETWORK
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.4cm,y=1.2cm]

  \readlist\Nnod{4,3,2} % array of number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Nstr{n,m,k} % array of string number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Cstr{x,h^{(\prev)},y} % array of coefficient symbol per layer
  \def\yshift{0.55} % shift last node for dots
  
  % LOOP over LAYERS
  \foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{
    \def\lay{\Ncnt} % alias of index of current layer
    \pgfmathsetmacro\prev{int(\Ncnt-1)} % number of previous layer
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\c=int(\i==\N); \y=\N/2-\i-\c*\yshift;
                 \x=\lay; \n=\nstyle;
                 \index=(\i<\N?int(\i):"\Nstr[\n]");}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
      % NODES
      \node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y) {$\strut\Cstr[\n]_{\index}$};
      
      % CONNECTIONS
      \ifnumcomp{\lay}{>}{1}{ % connect to previous layer
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\Nnod[\prev]}{ % loop over nodes in previous layer
          \draw[white,line width=1.2,shorten >=1] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
          \draw[connect] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
        }
        \ifnum \lay=\Nnodlen
          \draw[connect] (N\lay-\i) --++ (0.5,0); % arrows out
        \fi
      }{
        \draw[connect] (0.5,\y) -- (N\lay-\i); % arrows in
      }
      
    }
    \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.6] {$\vdots$}; % dots
  }
  
  % LABELS
  \node[above=3,align=center,mydarkgreen] at (N1-1.90) {Input\\[-0.2em]layer};
  \node[above=2,align=center,mydarkblue] at (N2-1.90) {Hidden\\[-0.2em]layers};
  \node[above=3,align=center,mydarkred] at (N\Nnodlen-1.90) {Output\\[-0.2em]layer};
  
  
  \begin{scope}[scale=0.75] 
    \draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain={-1.5:5}] (\x,{sin(\x^2 r)});
    \draw[blue!50!black, densely dotted] (-2,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (0,0) 
        -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_1$} coordinate[pos=0] (A);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (0.5,0) 
        -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (1.0,0) 
    -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (1.5,0) 
    -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (2.0,0) 
    -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);

    \draw[thick, <->] (-2,4) 
        -- node[left, midway, anchor=south, rotate=90, font=\bfseries] (Y) {$f(x)$} (-2,-2)
        -- node[below, pos=1, font=\bfseries] {Quad. points} (5,-2);
  \end{scope}
  
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

But it generates the following image: Which is not good.

[image]

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you copied this code from another source, since there are many inconsistencies. Anyway, you can add shifts to your `scope` where you drew the curve. See code below.

[image: drawing-custom-plots-and-spacing-them-in-tikz]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifnumcomp
\usepackage{listofitems} % for \readlist to create arrays

\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\colorlet{mywhite}{white!80!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{mydarkred}{myred!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{myblue!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkgreen}{mygreen!40!black}
\tikzstyle{node}=[very thick,circle,draw=myblue,minimum size=22,inner sep=0.5,outer sep=0.6]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[->,thick,mydarkblue,shorten >=1]
\tikzset{ % node styles, numbered for easy mapping with \nstyle
  node 1/.style={node,mydarkgreen,draw=mywhite,fill=mywhite!25},
  node 2/.style={node,mydarkblue,draw=mywhite,fill=mywhite!20},
  node 3/.style={node,mydarkred,draw=mywhite,fill=mywhite!20},
}
\def\nstyle{int(\lay<\Nnodlen?min(2,\lay):3)} % map layer number onto 1, 2, or 3

\begin{document}


% NEURAL NETWORK
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.4cm,y=1.2cm]

  \readlist\Nnod{4,3,2} % array of number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Nstr{n,m,k} % array of string number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Cstr{x,h^{(\prev)},y} % array of coefficient symbol per layer
  \def\yshift{0.55} % shift last node for dots
  
  % LOOP over LAYERS
  \foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{
    \def\lay{\Ncnt} % alias of index of current layer
    \pgfmathsetmacro\prev{int(\Ncnt-1)} % number of previous layer
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\c=int(\i==\N); \y=\N/2-\i-\c*\yshift;
                 \x=\lay; \n=\nstyle;
                 \index=(\i<\N?int(\i):"\Nstr[\n]");}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
      % NODES
      \node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y) {$\strut\Cstr[\n]_{\index}$};
      
      % CONNECTIONS
      \ifnumcomp{\lay}{>}{1}{ % connect to previous layer
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\Nnod[\prev]}{ % loop over nodes in previous layer
          \draw[white,line width=1.2,shorten >=1] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
          \draw[connect] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
        }
        \ifnum \lay=\Nnodlen
          \draw[connect] (N\lay-\i) --++ (0.5,0); % arrows out
        \fi
      }{
        \draw[connect] (0.5,\y) -- (N\lay-\i); % arrows in
      }
      
    }
    \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.6] {$\vdots$}; % dots
  }
  
  % LABELS
  \node[above=3,align=center,mydarkgreen] at (N1-1.90) {Input\\[-0.2em]layer};
  \node[above=2,align=center,mydarkblue] at (N2-1.90) {Hidden\\[-0.2em]layers};
  \node[above=3,align=center,mydarkred] at (N\Nnodlen-1.90) {Output\\[-0.2em]layer};
  
  
  \begin{scope}[scale=0.75,xshift=18cm,yshift=-2cm] % <---- HERE
    \draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain={-1.5:5}] (\x,{sin(\x^2 r)});
    \draw[blue!50!black, densely dotted] (-2,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (0,0) 
        -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_1$} coordinate[pos=0] (A);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (0.5,0) 
        -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (1.0,0) 
    -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (1.5,0) 
    -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);
    \draw[black, densely dashed] (2.0,0) 
    -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {$x_2$} coordinate[pos=0] (B);

    \draw[thick, <->] (-2,4) 
        -- node[left, midway, anchor=south, rotate=90, font=\bfseries] (Y) {$f(x)$} (-2,-2)
        -- node[below, pos=1, font=\bfseries] {Quad. points} (5,-2);
  \end{scope}
  
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

On a side note, you may use only `tikzset` and not `tikzstyle` which is deprecated nowadays.

Comment: Yes , I tried compiling multiple codes into one. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Also, can you suggest me how to improve my code to get it closer to my expected results. i.e 1. How to add dots for hidden layers (showing the several hidden layer in between) 2. How to make the output node to only 1 and also changing its label to summation (sign) , 3. How to improve the plot on the right? As I just implemented a sin function and did not know how to create something like the one I have on the right of my expected plot.

Comment: I suggest that you ask another question, since this website is meant to be single question thread. You will find some good souls and maybe you could find your answer by searching here. I'm pretty sure this has been already discussed and answered. Meanwhile, you can accept my answer if it suits your need.

Comment: Actually your answer does help a lot; but I was also looking for the custom plots. I really needed help in figuring out how to make a plot like the image I have uploaded.

Comment: As I previously said, one question by post is the best behaviour. Isolate you plot in a single MWE and ask another question. You will have a better luck to get answer like this.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks, I'll post another question.